# Does the Blender Internal renderer have an internal Light(ing) hierachy?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, lighting

I'm using Blender 2.77 and I have currently arrived at the native Blender Renderer engine, and I fully want to understand how it works and how I can use, adapt, modify it for my own Blender projects.

I've already read many free e-books, articles and watched many videos about it, but I want to be able to truly understand AND visualize its inner workings.

Unfortunately none of these sources offer much in-depth/under-the-hood insight on how stuff really works, so I still have lots of technical in-depth questions about the Blender internal Render engine like:

**QUESTION: Does Blender Render use an internal hierarchy for Light-Sources?**

This enables me to figure out (up front, and not by numerous trail-and-error renders) which BI light settings are going to influence and.or trickle down  onto other light/material/texture settings?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by an internal hierarchy of light sources? Why do you need it? What is the goal you want to achieve for having this.

Comment: What it seems is that you are seeking programming advice and information about the Blender source code. That is off-topic here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/7777. You will find people able to better help you on official dev irc or mail-list. It is very likely Blender Internal uses BVH for shadow-ray speedup. You can set the spatial acceleration structure under Performance tab in rendering properties.

Comment: @J.Bakker In Blender Internal computing of shadows rays is O(n) where n is number of lights, because there has to be a ray to every light source how it effects the surface. There are many acceleration structures to optimize this like spacial ones and importance ones - this is what he means with internal hieratchy of light-sources.

Comment: Btw. @IndogoWarrior9 you can omit the info of what you have red, it is irrelevant to the question and makes it harder to filter what you are after:)

Comment: @Jerryno: (1) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction(s). I've found more information now on the Blender Dev/Source/Render/Cycles/BVH page and will contact the chatroom later. (2) I've already downloaded the latest Blender source-code, to take a look at it, from the inside.
(3) One remark: Do not try to assume anything about what anyone wants to know nor what their motivation can be. its better to ask a question back to give them a change to better explain the knowledge they are seeking

Comment: @J.Bakker: I want to fully understand which BI "light-source" has the most (light/energy) influence over others "light-sources", so I can use 'm better determine their influence on my scene objects.

Comment: If that is the case, than there is no order of strengths of their lights. BI is a ray tracer. Note that the question does not state your last comments. Can you update the question to what you are looking for and keep in mind that this is stackexchange. Is the question really something that other people are also looking for. Or are you looking for a different platform to get your answers.